# Run multiple C++ projects from one parent dir in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, directory, repo

I need some help with creating a proper project that can run all of my C++ projects from the past.

I use to use an old AWS cloud IDE for C++, but it was deprecated a while back. I downloaded my files and stopped focusing on C++ for a while.

I have recently got back into C++ but I'm having some troubles with VS getting all my projects to run in one larger dir.

This is what my dir looks like from my previous IDE I downloaded back in 2018ish:

[image]

When I try running any of these projects, I receive an error stating : "Please select a valid startup item".

In my startup items drop-down though, there is only one option, the one I'm using:

[image]

Currently, the only way I can get these cpp files to run is by creating a new VS C++ console app project, and copying the code over. Is there a quick fix to getting these projects to run under one parent dir like above?

My hunch is I have to do something to the config properties file, but I'm not totally sure what it wants. I know I'm on a x64 based architecture and x86 is for 32bit so I have a feeling that my issue is stemming from that. This is what my conf file looks like:

[image]

I have tried changing it to x64 based as well though and that did not seem to fix anything:

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you!

I have tried changing the CppProperites.json config files to x64 based, but it did not fix it.
I have also tried creating a new project, and moving the dirs into it, but that still throws compilation errors.
I am new to Visual Studio and I have been looking around online but everything seems to lead me to a dead end and im not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Reads like you're interested in solutions, but in general VS likes one project, one job. It doesn't really even show your directory structure much respect.

Answer (score 0):

> Please select a valid startup item

You need to build the folder  to generate an exe  and select exe as start item.
[Open Folder support for C++ build systems in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/open-folder-projects-cpp?view=msvc-170)

> Is there a quick fix to getting these projects to run under one parent
> dir like above?

[How to: Create a C++ Project from Existing Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-create-a-cpp-project-from-existing-code?view=msvc-170)

On the File menu, select New > Project From Existing Code.

And the extension [Add Multiple Projects To Solution V2](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MaciejGudanowicz.AddMultipleProjectsToSolutionV2)  will help to add projects to a solution.

After creating the project, right click  project you want to start as start item.